# Webi: How to use double slider input control with dates?

Tags: date, slider, webi

My boss asked me to add a double slider input control for the date information on a report on Webi.
We have several columns and two of them display a date (start and end date of procedure). So I need to have two double slider, one for each date.

[image: Picture of the "Multiple Selections" menu in the input control selection window]

I've been searching for a whole day now and I know that it is not directly possible to use double slider with dates, because double slider only works with values (measures) and dates don't have that.
But I managed to create two more variables on the business layer. I used the following SQL function:

```
CAST(currentDate as Bigint))
```

These variables are displaying the date as numbers (e.g. 1090101 for 01.01.2009 (format is "dd-MM-yyyy")).

And it is working great! But it displays the dates as number, which is not possible to use for work. No one will know which date is 1090101. I could perhaps let both columns (date as date and date as number) in the report, so people could check the date they want to filter with the input control and select the right number on the slider. This could be a workaround, but not a clean one, I think.

[image: Example of the double slider for the date displayed as number]

I tried to change the format of the date as number to a date format, but then I could not use the slider anymore (even if the variable is a number).
I looked for a way to change the formatting of the values displayed on the slider, but with no luck.

So I'm asking for your help. Does anyone know how I could make this work?
Is there really no solutions for such a useful way of filtering data? I mean, filtering data by an interval of dates is surely something people want to do quite often, I assume.
Thank you in advance for your time.

(Version Webi : SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2 Support Pack 8 Patch 6,
Version: 14.2.8.3671)

Comment: I wish you joy and success in all your projets for 2022! :-)

That said, is there really no one able to help me on my problem?
Should I improve my question? Is there something missing for the understanding? Or should I simply wait more?
That's my first question here. Sorry if I'm doing it all wrong.

(Thanks Jakob for the suggestion to write this as comment and not a direct answer to my post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format your date value as year, month, day and then convert it to a number so the value you are filtering on makes a little more sense. Like this...

> =ToNumber(FormatDate([Your Date];"yyyyMMdd"))

[image]

It will be better than just an arbitrary number, but certainly not perfect since you will have large chunks of your range for which there never will be any corresponding data (e.g. 20211232 through 20220100).

What is wrong with just a Minimum and Maximum input controls? They are more intuitive and simple to create. Sometimes what your user or boss asks for is a bad idea and/or just not possible.

Comment: Hello Isaac, thanks you for your answer. You are right. I will try the minimum and maximum input controls and talk to my boss. I'm a new intern and I'm also new to Webi, so I have never encountered your suggestion yet. I'm eager to try and I will come back when it is done.

Comment: I have done it with the minimum and maximum and it worked. My boss found it less practical, but agreed that the most important was that it worked. Thank you for your help. I accepted your suggestion.